# Python Aysnchronous Client-Server Communication over Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, server, client

I'm working on a socket application where there is a server capable of supporting multiple clients.  On the server, I use a select to multiplex processing of different client requests. When a request is received on the server, the server generates a response and sends it to the client. This synchronous form of request/response has worked beautifully.

The challenge now is that the server can generate messages to send to clients asynchronously. I have plenty of ways of handling this on the server, but not sure how to do it well on the client.

The client can now receive messages at anytime, not just after sending a request. So, I need a way for the client to wait on messages from the server, while also sending requests the server asynchronously.

I currently have the client socket handling code in a thread and use queues to organize all the send requests to the server from other parts of the client code. In the socket handler, I'm using a select to know when a message has been received from the server. However, to process the send requests to the server, the client has to constantly check to see if there are send requests.

If it stick with select, I need to leave selectors.EVENT_WRITE enabled or the waiting on the reads will block an prevent sending any requests. This appears to work but results in a ton of busy looping when there are no send requests. I'd like to disable selectors.EVENT_WRITE when the request queue is empty, but that leads to issues with it not getting reenabled with the queue isn't empty.

I considered instead a thread for receiving and a thread for sending, but I've seen multiple people suggesting it is a bad idea to share a socket across threads.

My only other thoughts are to 1) switch to asyncio instead of using select, or 2) create separate sockets for sending and receiving, which seems like overkill since sockets are already bidirectional.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I guess ultimately I'm looking for suggestions on how to handle asynchronous communication across a socket as opposed to a simple request/response. Thanks!

Comment: Update: I am now trying a socket handler running in its own thread with a select that only checks for ready ready sockets. To be able to send requests through the main socket, I use a pair socket and a queue. The message on the pair socket triggers a read event in the main socket handler, which then pulls the send request off the queue and sends it out the main socket. It appears I can now read and write asynchronously.